# What is the use of numpy in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm a novice in AI & ML, and I always see
**"import numpy as np"**
So, I really want to know when is the usage of numpy? and what is the usage of it?
Ideally, when do we have to include in our code and be prepared for this library

Answer (score 2):

Numpy is a python library and it has a variety of use cases. It actually depends on the scenario you are working on.

As a novice ML learner myself, Numpy can prove to very useful when you work with ML algorithms, which typically involve working with arrays. Numpy tends to more versatile when compared to the traditional python List. Numpy offers the following features:

Smaller Memory Consumption than List
Implementation of Multi-Dimensional Arrays
NumPy arrays are faster than Python List
NumPy can be used to transform the Arrays Python does not have inbuilt support for Arrays Offers function like Reshape, Sort, Reverse, etc.

Usually, you have will have to deal with a lot to arrays of varying sizes and might have to sort or reshape. Numpy is very useful in that case